# how to reference to a thumb attribute in tastypie resource foreign key?

Tags: django, resources, thumbnails, foreign-key-relationship, tastypie

I use sorl_thumbnail to generate thumbnail in tastypie like:

```
class ImageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        always_return_data=True
        filtering = {
            "album": ('exact',),
        }
        queryset = Image.objects.all()
        cache = SimpleCache(timeout=100)
        resource_name = 'image'
        authorization = ImageAuthorization()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):

        im = get_thumbnail(bundle.obj.src, '200x200', quality=90)
        bundle.data['thumb'] = im.url
        return bundle
```

now I have an album resource, and I want to have the last uploaded image as the album's cover image, this is what I have so far:

```
class AlbumResource(ModelResource):

    cover_img = fields.ForeignKey('album.api.ImageResource')
```

this will only give me the cover image's url like

```
'album/v1/image/99'
```

what I want is when I get the resource, I can actully show the cover image,like

```
 {
    cover_img:path_to_cover_thumb,
 }
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

well I finally get it works here is what I did:

```
class AlbumResource(ModelResource):
    cover_img = fields.ForeignKey('album.api.ImageResource','cover_img')


class Meta:
    always_return_data=True

    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'album'
    authorization = AlbumAuthorization()

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    im = get_thumbnail(bundle.obj.cover_img.src, '200x200', quality=90)
    bundle.data['cover_thumb'] = im.url
    return bundle
```